# Update SQL table using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, sqlconnection, c#-datatable

I'm trying to update EpisodeId no:117 in the Episode table and it executes successfully but when I check the table it is not updated. int episode Id = 117;

```
int seriesNumber = 9;
int episodeNumber = 13;
string episodeType = "abnormal episode";
string title = "Reconsideration";
string notes = "recuring behaviour";

//connectionString
 
string connectionString = "data source=LAPTOP-VLO4EFFQ\\MSSQLSERVER01; database=DoctorWho; integrated Security=True;";

//connection using
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    
    conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection sucessfull");

    string query = "UPDATE tblEpisode " +
        "(SeriesNumber, EpisodeNumber, EpisodeType, Title, Notes)" +
        "(SET SeriesNumber=@SeriesNumber, EpisodeNumber=@EpisodeNumber, EpisodeType=@EpisodeType, Title=@Title, Notes=@Notes)" +
        "(WHERE EpisodeId=@EpisodeId)";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        //updating data in the sql table with the initial variables  
        command.Parameters.Add("@EpisodeId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = episodeId;
        command.Parameters.Add("@SeriesNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = seriesNumber;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EpisodeNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = episodeNumber;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EpisodeType", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = episodeType;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Title", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = title;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Notes", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = notes;

    }


    conn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("connection is closed!!");
}
```

Comment: How do you know the query executes correctly? The format of your update statement seems strange, I would expect `Update table set column = value where Id = x` without your complete second line and all those brackets.

Comment: You are not executing the command, use
`command.ExecuteNonQuery() `
Refer link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/executing-a-command#example

Comment: What Hemant said. Execute the query, using reader or command.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @HemantHalwai is right, you should also execute the command. But ExecuteReader seems strange, since you don't read anything.

Comment: Also, why is SET and WHERE in parens? And I don't see episodeId defined here.

Comment: Thanks @oerkelens, for correcting me, have updated my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your SQL update statement.Look at following for reference to Update Statement in SQL [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

There is also an easier way to add the parameters using the AddWithValue Method. [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Next, you are not executing the SQL command. For Update statements use the ExecuteNonQuery() method. [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Also as @Nikki9696 mentioned, episodeId is not declared. Make sure to declare episodeId with your other variables.

```
int episodeId = 117;
int seriesNumber = 9;
int episodeNumber = 13;
string episodeType = "abnormal episode";
string title = "Reconsideration";
string notes = "recuring behaviour";

//connectionString

string connectionString = "data source=LAPTOP-VLO4EFFQ\\MSSQLSERVER01; database=DoctorWho; integrated Security=True;";

//connection using
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

conn.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Connection sucessfull");

string query = "UPDATE tblEpisode " +        
    "SET SeriesNumber=@SeriesNumber, EpisodeNumber=@EpisodeNumber, EpisodeType=@EpisodeType, Title=@Title, Notes=@Notes " +
    " WHERE EpisodeId=@EpisodeId;";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    //updating data in the sql table with the initial variables  
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EpisodeId", episodeId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeriesNumber", seriesNumber);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EpisodeNumber", episodeNumber);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EpisodeType", episodeType);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", notes);
    
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}


conn.Close();
Console.WriteLine("connection is closed!!");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Cucumber thank you for your contribution it means a lot. It's telling me that I need to declare the scalar variable @SeriesNumber

Comment: Not sure why you would be getting that error exactly, but I have updated my answer to show an easier way to add the command parameters. This way you don't have to explicitly define the type of parameter. In addition, you can add the value and parameter in one method.